# Load Symbols Grayed Out Windows Performance Analyzer

Tags: debug-symbols, etw

I am following this tutorial:

https://dzone.com/articles/diagnosing-native-memory-leaks

When I get to the part about loading my symbols, I cannot because Trace->load symbols is grayed out. There are many answers about if symbols do not load after clicking (which would mean the symbol path is not set correctly), but I see none about the button being grayed out.

Also I have double checked my symbol path by running the application with WinDbg. I am getting no errors with that about my symbol path. I can also load symbols on other etl files. Is there a flag I need to enable for symbols to load on this etl?

Why would "Load Symbols" be grayed out in Windows Performance Analyzer?

I am on Windows 7 using WPT at this path
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit

The command I use is the same as the tutorials:

```
xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER
xperf -start heapsession -heap -pids 1234 -stackwalk HeapAlloc+HeapRealloc
```

Then

```
xperf -stop heapsession -d C:\temp\heap.etl
xperf -d C:\temp\kernel.etl
xperf -merge C:\temp\heap.etl C:\temp\kernel.etl C:\temp\combined.etl
```

Comment: open the ETL in Perfview and look if you see KernelTraceControl/ImageID/DbgID_RSDS events. They are required to load symbols

Comment: @magicandre1981 I do not see those. How do I get them to show up?

Comment: which windows and which WPT version do you use? And which xperf command have you used?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have updated

Comment: I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this is a known issue. The TH1 Version of the Windows 10 SDK/WPT is broken on Windows 7. This version misses the `KernelTraceControl/ImageID/DbgID_RSDS` events.

You should use the [Windows 8.1 WPT/SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891) or the today [released SDK for Windows 10 Build 10563](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/10/13/windows-10-sdk-preview-build-10563-released/) which includes the fix for that:

> Corrected problem that prevented trace capture on pre-Windows 8 OS
>   releases using xperf.exe and wpr.exe.

Comment: nice to hear this. Which WPT version do you use now?

Comment: Seems to have reverted. Same grayed out issue exists in 10.0.16299.91

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE Build 10586 is the only WPT that works in Windows 7.

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE sure this version works fine. use Perfview and look in the Event table for **KernelTraceControl/ImageID/DbgID_RSDS** events

Comment: @0xC0DEFACE also, this happens when you haven **xperf -d ** to stop tracing. the kernel.etl doesn't have the symbol data events.

Comment: Greyed on the WPA here on 1809 (17763) as well. Is there another way to check KernelTraceControl/ImageID/DbgID_RSDS? Thanks.

Comment: @LaurieStearn open the ETL file in perfview and look if the events are present in the ETL file.

Comment: These are WU Etl's. **Windows Kernel/EventTrace** is the only candidate record with start stop time name info, the rest are WUTrace. Doesn't look much like symbols going on in there. Plus MS [don't publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols) the offline symbols anymore. Thanks anyway.